# Vue scroll to anchor on another page?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a router link in my site header and when clicked goes to the page `/registration` which has a form on it. What I would like to achieve is when clicked it scrolls to the reg form using [vueScrollTo plugin](https://github.com/rigor789/vue-scrollto).

It's working now but not 100% how I would prefer it to behave. As of now when not on the `/registration` page and clicked it scrolls perfectly to the form however when I am on the `/registration` page itself and click the router link I get a warning

> trying to scroll to an element that is not on the page : undefined

I believe this is happening because I am firing the event on the mounted lifecycle. Is there a better solution to have this work properly?

`Site header component`

```html
<template>
  <router-link to="/registration"
    class="nav-row--primary__button"
    @click.native="scrollToRegForm()"
  >
    Sign up
  </router-link>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("/registration") > 0) {
      const regForm = document.getElementById("regForm");
      setTimeout(() => this.scrollToRegForm(regForm), 1);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    scrollToRegForm(element) {
      VueScrollTo.scrollTo(element, 1000);
    }
  }
}
```

`Registration page component`

```html
<div class="container--content spacing-ie" id="regForm">
  <RegistrationForm />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to firstly `yarn add vue-scrollto`, then add the following configuration to `nuxt.config.js`

```js
{
  modules: [
    'vue-scrollto/nuxt',
  ]
}
```

Then, this template should do the trick

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <p ref="regForm" style="background-color: hsl(210, 50%, 13%); height: 50vh; margin-top: 120vh"></p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueScrollTo from 'vue-scrollto'
Vue.use(VueScrollTo)

export default {
  mounted() {
    VueScrollTo.scrollTo(this.$refs.regForm, 1000, { easing: 'linear' })
  },
}
</script>
```

Tried this coming from another page and it is working great, no need to call `vue-scrollto` from this page neither, move by using a simple `<nuxt-link>`.

---

This documentation page can help you understand `$refs`: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements

Answer (score 0):

With setTimeout:

```
methods: {
scrollToRegForm(element) {
  this.$router.push('/regForm')
  setTimeout(() =>{
    VueScrollTo.scrollTo(element, 1000);
  }, 1000)
}
```

}