# How not to scroll down a page after a route change in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I have Nuxt project. When I change the route from `http://localhost:3000/catalog/postery` to `http://localhost:3000/catalog/postery/all?photos%5B%5D=262` my page is scrolled up to the top, and only after my route is changing

My file scrollBehavior.js:

```
export default async function (to, from, savedPosition) {
  
  if (
    (to.path.indexOf("/catalog/") !== -1 &&
      to.path.indexOf("/all") === -1 &&
      Object.keys(to.query).length > 0) || 
    (to.path.indexOf("/search") !== -1 && Object.keys(to.query).length > 0) || 
    (to.name === "product-type-id" && Object.keys(to.query).length > 0) || 
    (from.name === "product-type-id" &&
      to.name === "product-type-id" &&
      to.params.type != from.params.type) 
  ) {
    return;
  }

  if (to.path.indexOf("/catalog/") !== -1 && savedPosition != null) {
    return { x: 0, y: savedPosition.y };
  }

  return { x: 0, y: 0 };
}
```

How I can prevent scroll up before changing route?

Comment: So, if you don't want to scroll up, what do you want? Stay at the same level of scrolling on th next page? What is the purpose and what are you targeting with this behavior?

Comment: @kissu i want that my current page dont scroll up before my route is changing. I want save position that i have before going to new route

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you do want to:

- click on a link
- start to render the page
- scroll to top

From the Vue router [documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html#async-scrolling), it looks like you can use this kind of code

`/app/router.scrollBehavior.js`

```js
export default function () {
  return { x: 0, y: 0, behavior: 'smooth' }
}
```

You could maybe also make it conditional or with a `setTimeout` like this

```js
export default function (to, from, savedPosition) {
  if (to.path === '/my-cool-path') {
    return { x: 0, y: 0, behavior: 'smooth' }
  }
}
```

```js
export default function (to, from, savedPosition) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({ x: 0, y: 0, behavior: 'smooth' })
    }, 2000)
  })
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68290633/8816585) using `vue-scrollto` can also maybe help.

Last resort would be to use some [transitions](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/transitions) to hide the ugly jitter/loading, this can actually be pretty sexy.

Comment: new Promise helped me