# Navigating with nuxt-link to anchor/hash on a different page is not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router

I want to navigate to a specific section of a page from another page. So I added the scrollBehavior function in router object in nuxt.config.js file like this:

```js
router: {
    scrollBehavior(to) {
      if (to.hash) {
        return {
          selector: to.hash,
          behavior: "smooth"
        };
      }
    }
  }
```

My 'pages' directory tree is like this:

```
pages/
   index.vue
   parent.vue
   random.vue
```

In default.vue of 'layouts' directory I wrote the navbar:

```html
<button @click="$router.push({ name: 'parent' })">Parent One</button>
<button @click="$router.push({ name: 'parent', hash: '#sec2' })">Parent Two</button>
```

Inside parent.vue I have two sections:

```html
<div class="sec-1" id="sec1">
      <h1>Parent One</h1>
      <p>...
      </p>
</div>
<div class="sec-2" id="sec2">
      <h1>Parent Two</h1>
      <p>...
      </p>
</div>
```

Now, The problem is When I click the 'parent two' button from random.vue file it doesn't work. but when I am in parent.vue file and click the button it scrolls to the second section. But I want to navigate to the second section from random.vue page. If I write the exact code in a vue project then it works fine but doesn't work in nuxt project. But I need to do it in my Nuxt project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68819388/8816585), you can setup the following in a [`~/app/router.scrollBehavior.js`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-router#scrollbehavior) file

```js
export default function(to, from, savedPosition) {
  console.log("this is the hash", to.hash)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (to.hash) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({
          selector: to.hash,
          behavior: "smooth"
        })
      }, 10)
    }
  })
}
```

And it should work well. Maybe just silently fail when it does not find the selector or apply it only on specific paths.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by using this module: https://nuxt.com/modules/nuxt-anchorscroll along with replacing `<RouterView/>` with `<NuxtPage/>`