# vue router scroll to hash without refresh the component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

I am using Vue 3 and vue-router 4.

If I have a hash link in a component

```html
<router-link :to="{ hash: '#l1' }">Section - 1</router-link>
<router-link :to="{ hash: '#l2' }">Section - 2</router-link>
...
<section id="l1">...</section>
<section id="l2">...</section>
```

And in my router I have

```js
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (to.hash) {
      return {
        el: to.hash,
      }
    }
  },
})
```

Clicking on the router links scrolls to the desired position, but during the scroll the component is re-created, so I lost all data previously fetched from the API.

Is there a way to avoid component re-creation if the navigation is within the same page?

**UPDATE** If I click on any of this hash links the component's setup method runs again so the component is re-created. If I click on the same hash link, it only scrolls, the component stays alive.
Clicking on any other hash link the component is re-created again.

Comment: Have you tried using router.push?

Comment: Maybe try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69822619/8816585 I've also achieved it with the following package: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70146096/8816585

Comment: `router.push` also recreate the component

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just use a normal link Tag for that case:

```
<a href="#l1">Section - 1</a>
```

If you want to use a `<router-link>`, read [this issue (https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-handle-anchors-bookmarks-with-vue-router/14563)](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-handle-anchors-bookmarks-with-vue-router/14563), where many suggestions are given on how to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Using an `a` in a SPA context may cause quite some issues usually. And this can probably be achieved while keeping the usage of the vue router.

Comment: That's why I added a link to some `<router-link>`-based solutions.  But thanks for elaborating on why it's probably the better idea to use `<router-link>` in this case.

Comment: I'm saying that mainly because I saw a lot of people nuking their SPA with some `a` tags. Common mistake around here. Wasn't particularly blaming here.

Comment: Using the `a` tag results the same, the component is re-created. I have checked the forum topic, but it is a different problem and the solution does not work in this case.