# NuxtLink to hash

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use a NuxtLink to scroll to an anchor tag. From the docs I see I need to create this file `app/router.scrollBehavior.js` and place my code there.

For example, this works. It scrolls 500px in the y axis, but what I really want is to scroll to the hash.

```js
export default function (to, from, savedPosition) {
  if (to.hash) {
    return { x: 0, y: 500 }
  }
}
```

**Events Page**

```html
<div
  v-for="(event, i) in events"
  :id="event.id"
  :ref="event.id"
  :key="i"
>
</div>
```

**Navigation Component**

```html
<NuxtLink
  v-for="item in items"
  :key="`item.id"
  :to="item.href"
>
  {{ item.name }}
</NuxtLink>
```

I haven't been able to make it scroll to the hash. I tried several options an none of them seems to work. For example:

**Does not work** (I also tested with selector instead of el)

```js
export default function (to, from, savedPosition) {
  if (to.hash) {
    return {
      el: to.hash,
      behavior: 'smooth',
    }
  }
}
```

**Does not work**

```js
export default function (to, from, savedPosition) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (to.hash) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({
          el: to.hash,
          behavior: 'smooth',
        })
      }, 500)
    }
  })
}
```

Any ideas about what it could be the problem?

Comment: I achieved it once [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70146096/8816585).

Comment: Do you have what you're expecting in `to.hash` and also, how is your template looking?

Comment: @kissu The `to.hash` looks something like this `#world-event`

Comment: What about the template?

Comment: I updated the question and added the events page and navigation component.

Comment: So, what is not working? Did you tried my linked answer above?

Comment: The scroll is not working. I did not use Vue.Scroll before so I'm trying your solution.  Thx!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to smoothly scroll to an element via a hash in Nuxt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70140870/how-to-smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-via-a-hash-in-nuxt)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so finally this is what worked for me. I had to install Vue-Scroll and inside `app/router.scrollBehavior.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueScrollTo from 'vue-scrollto'
Vue.use(VueScrollTo)

export default function (to, from, savedPosition) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (to.hash) {
        VueScrollTo.scrollTo(to.hash, 300, { easing: 'linear', offset: -60 })
      }
    }, 500)
  })
}
```

I used this answer as a reference [How to smoothly scroll to an element via a hash in Nuxt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70140870/how-to-smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-via-a-hash-in-nuxt/70146096#70146096) but I had to change the `setTimeOut` time from 10ms to 500ms because it wasn't working properly on my static page.