# How to scroll to section with vue-smooth-scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, scrollbar, smoothing

I'm creating a portfolio with nuxt.js and i'm using a node module which is [vue-smooth-scrollbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-smooth-scrollbar) to have a smooth scroll in my page content.

The problem is I don't know how to scroll to a specific element in my scrolling content because it is implementing a new way of scrolling with a translate3D.

Does anyone know if there is a function to this package so I can scroll to a specific container with an anchor?

Comment: Hi, I have some answers regarding the scroll: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8816585+scroll Tell me if any of those are enough or if you really want me to check your specific package.

Comment: Otherwise, could you please provide more details regarding your template?

Comment: @kissu Thanks for replying and sorry for the late answer. I've searched for answers in your link but the problem is about the vue component which is vue-smooth-scrollbar. I know how to scroll to anchor but the component makes it impossible because i think it is not enough developped to do this kind of thing. I don't want you to lose you time on this library but if you have an alternative solution to have a smooth scroll and to be able to scroll to a specific anchor on my page, your solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you're talking about is 6 months old with no documentation and it's more aimed towards the actual smoothness of the **scrollbars**.

My [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68290633/8816585) is about how to scroll to a specific element in your page. This is also just 2kB so good enough.

This being usable anywhere on the page

```js
VueScrollTo.scrollTo(this.$refs.regForm, 1000, { easing: 'linear' })
```

You can of course also scroll to [a hash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70146096/8816585).

---

Otherwise, smooth scroll is also available in [JS vanilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll).